# Django how to implement updateview in parent and child tables

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have two models

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
role_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
super_id = models.IntegerField(default=1)


class AdminDetails(models.Model):
    user =  models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, default=1,unique=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

and i have a form for creating/updating details in forms.py

```
class AdminCreationForm(forms.Form):
   username = forms.CharField(label=_('Username'))
   password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
   reenter_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
   email = forms.EmailField(label=_('Email'))
   first_name = forms.CharField(label=_('First Name'))
   last_name = forms.CharField(label=_('Last Name'))
   phone_number = forms.CharField(label=_('Phone Number'))
   address = forms.CharField(label=_('Address'))
```

I have a update view in  views.py like this . But can only update to single AdminDetails model only.

```
class AdminUpdateView(UpdateView):
    fields = ('phone_number', 'address')
    model = models.AdminDetails
    template_name = 'accounts/admin_form.html'
```

How can i update username ,first name along with this address in a single updateview ???

Comment: You are using abstract user, so why one more model, you can add address and all that in same model? The only reason I can see if you have multiple address and phone number. If you want that then create two Model forms and add it on the same page.

Comment: It's probably easier if you don't use `UpdateView` if you're fairly new to Django and class-based views. You need to tweak it quite a bit to make it work for two models. Just write a function-based view as you learned in the tutorials and create the two objects separately based on your form.cleaned_data. Once you have that, you can optimise a bit by using a `FormView` and do the saving in the `AdminCreationForm`'s `save()` method.

Comment: To @BidhanMajhi's comment: if different users can have different types of profiles it makes sense to keep the `AdminDetails` in a different model (so that you can have users who don't have `AdminDetails`). But are you sure you want a `ForeignKey` to `User` and not a `OneToOneField` to ensure only one profile? Now, to fetch a user's address you'll have to do `user.admindetails_set.first().address`  (and `first()` is just arbitrary) or `[details.address for details in user.admindetails_set.all()]` instead of just `user.admin_details.address`.